# Upgrading Asp.Net Core 2.2 to 3.1 using Microsoft.Identity.Web - No authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'AzureADJwtBearer'

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-ad-msal

I'm in the process of updating an Asp.Net Core 2.2 application to 3.1.

We use Microsoft.Identity.Web to handle Azure AD authentication.  I changed our security configuration as as follow:

ConfigureSerivces

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(configuration)
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddScheme<ApiKeyAuthenticationSchemeOptions, ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler
    (AuthenticationSchemes.ApiKey, null);
```

And Configure

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseMiddleware<LogUsernameMiddleware>();
app.UseEndpoints(p =>
{
    p.MapControllers();
});
```

But is throwing the following exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=No authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'AzureADJwtBearer'. The registered schemes are: Bearer, ApiKey. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().Add[SomeAuthHandler]("AzureADJwtBearer",...)?
  Source=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.<AuthenticateAsync>d__13.MoveNext() in /_/src/Http/Authentication.Core/src/AuthenticationService.cs:line 67
```

Not sure what part is not registering the authentication/authorization settings.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in our code, We were using a class with const string to return either ApiKey, AzureADJwtBearer or All as AuthenticationSchemes for controllers but AzureADJwtBearer as been replaced with just Bearer.

Thank you,